# Manhwa/manhua where the main character has to climb a massive cliff to sign in

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, cultivation

This is a Manhua/manhwa where the main character has to sign in according to the system and get rewarded for it.

There was a scene where the main character has to climb a massive cliff to sign in and then his cultivation soars.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Hi, i read it last year and i am so frustrated i can't find the title now ;(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like it may be the isekai *Sign In The Mystery Box To Dominate The World Of Cultivation*. When MC goes to a "sign in" location, he gets loot boxes.

[image: sign in location detected { alchemy pavilion} do you want to sign up]

[image: It's not a big deal not signing in. Let's just focus on cultivation]

The only English versions seem to be fan translations. Original title: [签到盲盒称霸修真界](https://m.ac.qq.com/comic/index/id/652373)

Comment: Sounds like it might be it!